# nestjs Docker build error: can not find tsconfig.build.json

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node AS builder


WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: Dockerfile
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:z
    environment:
      NODE_ENV : development
      TZ: "${TZ:-America/Los_Angeles}"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

After I run the docker-compose up -d,  I can have the error from the console :

Error  Could not find TypeScript configuration file "tsconfig.build.json". Please, ensure that you are running this command in the appropriate directory (inside Nest workspace).

I have tried to copy and paste tsconfig.build.json to the docker, but it still does not work.

please help.

Comment: Your final image (starting from the second `FROM node` line) doesn't include the Typescript setup.  You shouldn't need it, though, since you're copying the built  application from the first stage.  Do you need something more like `CMD node dist/index.js`?

Answer (score 7):

In your last step, you never copy over the `tsconfig.build.json` file or the `tsconfig.json`. Though, I don't see why you're using `start:dev` when you've already built the server in the docker image. You should just be calling `node dist/main`

Comment: May be he is trying to do development, while running the app in a docker container. The app is running on watch mode and the nest/cli trying to find the tsconfig.json. Thats why, he needs to copy the tsconfig.json while building image or to map volume inside the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Docker, but I've got the same error:

`Error Could not find TypeScript configuration file "tsconfig.build.json". Please, ensure that you are running this command in the appropriate directory (inside Nest workspace).`

I solved this by deleting the `dist` folder and `npm run start:dev` again.

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong with the director of builder copy   try not to copy builder and let "**npm run build**" do all the work , for the previous code it should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).